# How to save fragment state while using Navigation component and Bottom Navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have four fragment in bottom navigation and one activity, Bottom navigation is set up using NavController like this

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.dashboardNavHostFragment).apply {
        setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph , bundle)
    }
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

I'm passing some data in bundle that I require in my first fragment of bottom nav.
The problem is it works fine the data comes in the fragment like this

```
private val args: PlayerFeedFragmentArgs by navArgs()
private var data: String? = args.name
```

but when I navigate using bottom nav and come back to my first fragment the data comes as *null*
I tried saving data using

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putString("name", data)
}
```

and getting data back in onViewCreated but it didn't work because onSaveInstanceState does not get called when switching between fragments of bottom nav.

How can I save the incoming args from the activity in my first fragment so that when I switch fragments from bottom nav it stays the same.

Comment: You can use single **view model**, which will be shared between these fragments.

Comment: Use ```SharedViewModel``` for **Fragments** that need the same data.

Comment: Actually I don't want to share data with other fragments of bottom nav, I just want to save the state of my first fragment so that when I come back to it from other fragments the args or the name is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a SavedStateViewModel handler

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateViewModelFactory

A quick example can be found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5212210-jetpack-saved-state-for-viewmodel-getting-started):

Using this method, you don't have to share your data with other fragments.